# Extract timestamp from bag for some topics without the time

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbag, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

unfortunately, I recorded a very long bag file containing some topics that have a timestamp and two topics that do not include it since I forgot to add it before to launch the ROS node.
Unfortunately, all the topics have different sampling time, so I cannot find a valid method to reference the value recorded in the topics without the timestamp against the timestamp from the other topics.

Is there a way to add the timestamp also in the topics that do not include it?
I was hoping that when you launch "`rosbag record -a`" the utility somehow keeps trace of the time acquisition. :)

This is the topic list and the topics without the timestamp are loadcell and steering.
Hope you can help me, thank you!

```
topics:      /diagnostics                 692 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticArray
             /joy                       18326 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Joy                
             /robo_explorer/cmd_vel     18326 msgs    : geometry_msgs/Twist            
             /robo_explorer/enc          4537 msgs    : std_msgs/String                
             /robo_explorer/io_status   18326 msgs    : robo_explorer/robo_io          
             /robo_explorer/loadcell     7049 msgs    : std_msgs/String                
             /robo_explorer/steering     9887 msgs    : std_msgs/String                
             /robo_explorer/sys          4538 msgs    : std_msgs/String                
             /robo_explorer/velocity     4537 msgs    : std_msgs/String                
             /rosout                    56497 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log               (4 connections)
             /rosout_agg                56484 msgs    : rosgraph_msgs/Log
```

This is the [test.bag file](http://www.skeetty.com/test.bag) as reference.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415696/extract-timestamp-from-bag-for-some-topics-without-the-time/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2023-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-23**:
quick comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but `rosbag` does store the reception time with each message it records. It will be wildly inaccurate though (well .. depends on your requirements) compared to stamps stored in `header.stamp`. See #q199941 and #q318536 for earlier questions, and [wiki/rosbag/Cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) for a collection of example Python `rosbag` processing scripts.

> Is there a way to add the timestamp also in the topics that do not include it?

no, not without changing your `.msg` definition and completely rewriting/processing the `.bag` file.

You *can* figure out reception time for all messages recorded, but you wouldn't then "add it" like you seem to be asking.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-23**:
Thank you a lot for your support. I already tried that links before opening the topic since I wasn't able to retrieve the time in any way by using that examples. The loadcell topic is just a string with values separated by a comma. I uploaded the bag file in the main topic just for reference.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-23**:
The first example in the Cookbook () basically does this:

```
for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():
    ...
```

The `t` there is the time the message was received/recorded.

Just to clarify: you will not somehow get a "timestamp" as part of the messages that were recorded. Rosbag does not change what it records (actually, it doesn't even deserialise the msgs it receives, so it only records a binary blob). The only thing you can do is ask Rosbag to give you the time at which it recorded the message.

That is what the `t` is in the snippet above.

> The loadcell topic is just a string with values separated by a comma

pedantic, but that's of course never a good idea in a strongly typed system such as ROS.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-23**:
I already tried that specific example but it only gives me the original topic as output without any timestamp.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-23**:
I'm confused.

The *only* time information you would have access to in case of a message stream in a `.bag` where the `.msg` themselves don't contain a `std_msgs/Header` would be the time at which each individual message got recorded.

*That* time is what you have access to in the `t` variable in the line:

```
for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():
```

Notice the `t` in the `topic, msg, t` (unpacked) `tuple`.

That `t` is not part of your `.msg` definition. It's what Rosbag itself records, in addition to the message contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To make it really concrete: the following should print the time `t` at which message `msg` was recorded followed by the contents for each message received on the topic `/robo_explorer/loadcell`:

```
for topic, msg, t in rosbag.Bag('input.bag').read_messages():
    if topic == "/robo_explorer/loadcell":
        print (f"{t}: '{msg}'")
```

(haven't checked the syntax, so there may be errors)

That would be the best you could do in the absence of a `std_msgs/Header` field.

And note again: this would get you time at which the message was recorded, not when it was published.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-23**:
I'm not a python expert, so probably I had to change the code you provide, however, I tried your code as it is but unfortunately it just prints a series of: {t}: '{msg}'

```
{t}: '{msg}'
{t}: '{msg}'
{t}: '{msg}'
{t}: '{msg}'
```

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-23**:
Ok, my fault, I needed to check the syntax, now it works and prints the timestamp! Thank you for your support!

```
print (t, msg)
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-23**:
As I wrote:

> haven't checked the syntax, so there may be errors

I've added the `f` prefix, to make it an f-string. Note that if you're not using Python 3, it still won't work.

Finally: this is all just an example. Please experiment and use it to arrive at a satisfactory solution.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-23**:
Thank you for your help and support, I was able to correctly recover the timestamp.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-24**:
Just to make it extra clear: you did not recover a / the timestamp.

You're now using the time Rosbag recorded your message.

Those are two very different things.

**Comment by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on 2023-05-24**:
Yes, you have reason, I should edit my previous comment to avoid misunderstandings. I just recovered the time related to when rosbag utility received the message from the original topic. It is still OK for me since it was just a test. EDIT: I cannot change my previous post, unfortunately.